# Laptop keyboard and mouse not working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo ideapad 110s running Ubuntu 17.04 and the mouse and keyboard on my laptop is not responding. It happened once about a month ago, the battery died and the next time i booted it up the mouse and keyboard worked perfectly again. Then about a week ago the battery died and now neither is working again. I'm really at a loss any advice is appreciated. I have tried restarting it and even let the battery die. I've searched the website for driver's but they are all for windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB keyboard and mouse you'll be able to troubleshoot and probably fix this problem.

If you don't, first fully charge up the battery until the battery light is solid white.  Then boot up the laptop.  Make sure you haven't toggled the touchpad to "disable".

If this doesn't fix it, power off the laptop, remove the battery for a minute or so, reinstall the battery and boot the laptop.  Looking at your user manual it's not clear that the battery is user serviceable so you may not be able to remove it.

If this also doesn't work, try entering the BIOS when the laptop starts up.  This should work unless the keyboard is broken at a level lower than the OS.

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1182643/Lenovo-Ideapad-110.html?page=13#manual

The user manual also provides information on how to reset your Ideapad back to factory defaults.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm so infuriated right now if you're reading this don't buy lenovo laptops. This pos is only a couple months old and I have had so many problems with it. I've called tech support and they said they would replace it but it would take two - 3 weeks and I would have to pay shipping and handling. What a serious rippoff. Never agian